# Conditional formatting messes up when FILTER results change

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I have a sheet that outputs varying results from a FILTER function, depending on how you set some checkboxes.

One of the results columns has a conditional formatting rule that changes the colour of just that column depending upon the contents of the cell.  It's a really simple one that says, if TEXT CONTAINS Matt, then make the cell blue.

But sometimes, and only sometimes, when the checkboxes are changed, so the results list becomes shorter, some of the conditional formatting colours stay in the lower cells even though the cell no longer contains any text at all.

Has anyone seen this before, or knows a solution?

Comment: Maybe you can implement an additional conditional formatting rule - like if cell is empty - make the cell color "None"? If this does not help - it would be easier if you could provide a copy of your spreadsheet (after removing private information).

Comment: Adding the cell is empty rule fixed it.

Comment: Glad it helped!